# Why is this FFT code not working to extract frequencies from a wav audio?

Tags: java, audio, fft, pitch-detection

I'm quite new to audio processing and i'm trying to extract frequencies from a wav file. As research papers stated i put the wav audio into a byte array and segmented and trying to apply FFT to get the frequencies from the audio. However the problem is even when i enter a audio track with only one note played (With no noise) i get a lot of frequencies as a result where as i'm supposed to get one.

My guess is something is wrong with the FFT code because the audio gets segmented properly.

Thanks everyone in advance,

My fft code

```
  public void getFFT(double[] x, int a) {

    double amp[] = new double[512];

    double firstSum;
    double secSum;
    double twoPInjk;
    double[][] s = new double[512][2];
    for (int j = 0; j < 512; j++) {
        firstSum = 0;
        secSum = 0;
        FreqArr[j] = (j * sampleRate) / (512);
        for (int k = 0; k < 512; k++) {
            twoPInjk = ((2 * Math.PI) / 512) * (j * k);
            firstSum += x[k] * Math.cos(twoPInjk);
            secSum += x[k] * Math.sin(twoPInjk);
        }
        amp[j] = Math.abs(Math.sqrt(Math.pow(firstSum, 2) + Math.pow(secSum, 2)));
    }
    highest(amp, a);
}

public void highest(double[] amp, int a) {
    String note;
    double all = 0;
    double max_magnitude = -1;
    int max_index = -1;

    for (int i = 0; i < (512); i++) {

        all = all + amp[i];

        if (amp[i] > max_magnitude) {
            max_magnitude = amp[i];
            max_index = i;
        }
    }
    double freq = 0;
    int cnt = 0;

    freq = max_index * (sampleRate / 2) / (512);
    System.out.println("Maximum_index: " + max_index);
    System.out.println("Sample rate: " + sampleRate);

      System.out.println(freq + " is the frequnecy");
}
```

my result (for the 1 second audio with only one note played)

> Sample rate 44100
>   My data size 70376 
>   My myBitsPerSample 16
>   My channels 2
>   My myByteRate 176400
>   My Length 0.7983219954648526
>   0.7983219954648526
>   44100.0
>   Max_index: 56
>   Sample rate: 44100.0
>   2411.71875 is the frequnecy
>   Max_index: 256
>   Sample rate: 44100.0
>   11025.0 is the frequnecy
>   Max_index: 256
>   Sample rate: 44100.0
>   11025.0 is the frequnecy
>   Max_index: 129
>   Sample rate: 44100.0
>   5555.56640625 is the frequnecy
>   Max_index: 511
>   Sample rate: 44100.0
>   22006.93359375 is the frequnecy
>   Max_index: 256
>   Sample rate: 44100.0
>   11025.0 is the frequnecy
>   Max_index: 152
>   Sample rate: 44100.0
>   6546.09375 is the frequnecy
>   Max_index: 422
>   Sample rate: 44100.0
>   18174.0234375 is the frequnecy
>   Max_index: 26
>   Sample rate: 44100.0
>   1119.7265625 is the frequnecy
>   Max_index: 462
>   Sample rate: 44100.0
>   19896.6796875 is the frequnecy
>   Max_index: 450
>   Sample rate: 44100.0
>   19379.8828125 is the frequnecy
>   Max_index: 201
>   Sample rate: 44100.0
>   8656.34765625 is the frequnecy
>   Max_index: 383
>   Sample rate: 44100.0
>   16494.43359375 is the frequnecy
>   Max_index: 6
>   Sample rate: 44100.0
>   258.3984375 is the frequnecy
>   Max_index: 385
>   Sample rate: 44100.0
>   16580.56640625 is the frequnecy
>   Max_index: 100
>   Sample rate: 44100.0
>   4306.640625 is the frequnecy
>   Max_index: 15
>   Sample rate: 44100.0
>   645.99609375 is the frequnecy
>   Max_index: 421
>   Sample rate: 44100.0
>   18130.95703125 is the frequnecy
>   Max_index: 256
>   Sample rate: 44100.0
>   11025.0 is the frequnecy
>   Max_index: 0
>   Sample rate: 44100.0
>   0.0 is the frequnecy
>   Max_index: 483
>   Sample rate: 44100.0
>   20801.07421875 is the frequnecy
>   Max_index: 0
>   Sample rate: 44100.0
>   0.0 is the frequnecy
>   Max_index: 134
>   Sample rate: 44100.0
>   5770.8984375 is the frequnecy
>   Max_index: 123
>   Sample rate: 44100.0
>   5297.16796875 is the frequnecy
>   Max_index: 2
>   Sample rate: 44100.0
>   86.1328125 is the frequnecy
>   Max_index: 378
>   Sample rate: 44100.0
>   16279.1015625 is the frequnecy
>   Max_index: 491
>   Sample rate: 44100.0
>   21145.60546875 is the frequnecy
>   Max_index: 125
>   Sample rate: 44100.0
>   5383.30078125 is the frequnecy
>   Max_index: 242
>   Sample rate: 44100.0
>   10422.0703125 is the frequnecy
>   Max_index: 267
>   Sample rate: 44100.0
>   11498.73046875 is the frequnecy
>   Max_index: 257
>   Sample rate: 44100.0
>   11068.06640625 is the frequnecy
>   Max_index: 128
>   Sample rate: 44100.0
>   5512.5 is the frequnecy
>   Max_index: 496
>   Sample rate: 44100.0
>   21360.9375 is the frequnecy
>   Max_index: 350
>   Sample rate: 44100.0
>   15073.2421875 is the frequnecy
>   Max_index: 75
>   Sample rate: 44100.0
>   3229.98046875 is the frequnecy
>   Max_index: 127
>   Sample rate: 44100.0
>   5469.43359375 is the frequnecy
>   Max_index: 473
>   Sample rate: 44100.0
>   20370.41015625 is the frequnecy
>   Max_index: 35
>   Sample rate: 44100.0
>   1507.32421875 is the frequnecy
>   Max_index: 420
>   Sample rate: 44100.0
>   18087.890625 is the frequnecy
>   Max_index: 413
>   Sample rate: 44100.0
>   17786.42578125 is the frequnecy
>   Max_index: 136
>   Sample rate: 44100.0
>   5857.03125 is the frequnecy
>   Max_index: 93
>   Sample rate: 44100.0
>   4005.17578125 is the frequnecy
>   Max_index: 251
>   Sample rate: 44100.0
>   10809.66796875 is the frequnecy
>   Max_index: 431
>   Sample rate: 44100.0
>   18561.62109375 is the frequnecy
>   Max_index: 490
>   Sample rate: 44100.0
>   21102.5390625 is the frequnecy
>   Max_index: 221
>   Sample rate: 44100.0
>   9517.67578125 is the frequnecy
>   Max_index: 364
>   Sample rate: 44100.0
>   15676.171875 is the frequnecy
>   Max_index: 19
>   Sample rate: 44100.0
>   818.26171875 is the frequnecy
>   Max_index: 487
>   Sample rate: 44100.0
>   20973.33984375 is the frequnecy
>   Max_index: 350
>   Sample rate: 44100.0
>   15073.2421875 is the frequnecy
>   Max_index: 243
>   Sample rate: 44100.0
>   10465.13671875 is the frequnecy
>   Max_index: 384
>   Sample rate: 44100.0
>   16537.5 is the frequnecy
>   Max_index: 403
>   Sample rate: 44100.0
>   17355.76171875 is the frequnecy
>   Max_index: 56
>   Sample rate: 44100.0
>   2411.71875 is the frequnecy
>   Max_index: 151
>   Sample rate: 44100.0
>   6503.02734375 is the frequnecy
>   Max_index: 447
>   Sample rate: 44100.0
>   19250.68359375 is the frequnecy
>   Max_index: 501
>   Sample rate: 44100.0
>   21576.26953125 is the frequnecy
>   Max_index: 377
>   Sample rate: 44100.0
>   16236.03515625 is the frequnecy
>   Max_index: 465
>   Sample rate: 44100.0
>   20025.87890625 is the frequnecy
>   Max_index: 417
>   Sample rate: 44100.0
>   17958.69140625 is the frequnecy
>   Max_index: 259
>   Sample rate: 44100.0
>   11154.19921875 is the frequnecy
>   Max_index: 34
>   Sample rate: 44100.0
>   1464.2578125 is the frequnecy
>   Max_index: 327
>   Sample rate: 44100.0
>   14082.71484375 is the frequnecy
>   Max_index: 280
>   Sample rate: 44100.0
>   12058.59375 is the frequnecy
>   Max_index: 271
>   Sample rate: 44100.0
>   11670.99609375 is the frequnecy
>   Max_index: 92
>   Sample rate: 44100.0
>   3962.109375 is the frequnecy
>   Max_index: 141
>   Sample rate: 44100.0
>   6072.36328125 is the frequnecy
>   Max_index: 467
>   Sample rate: 44100.0
>   20112.01171875 is the frequnecy
>   Max_index: 123
>   Sample rate: 44100.0
>   5297.16796875 is the frequnecy
>   Max_index: 388
>   Sample rate: 44100.0
>   16709.765625 is the frequnecy
>   Max_index: 122
>   Sample rate: 44100.0
>   5254.1015625 is the frequnecy
>   Max_index: 386
>   Sample rate: 44100.0
>   16623.6328125 is the frequnecy
>   Max_index: 464
>   Sample rate: 44100.0
>   19982.8125 is the frequnecy
>   Max_index: 231
>   Sample rate: 44100.0
>   9948.33984375 is the frequnecy
>   Max_index: 95
>   Sample rate: 44100.0
>   4091.30859375 is the frequnecy
>   Max_index: 112
>   Sample rate: 44100.0
>   4823.4375 is the frequnecy
>   Max_index: 260
>   Sample rate: 44100.0
>   11197.265625 is the frequnecy
>   Max_index: 383
>   Sample rate: 44100.0
>   16494.43359375 is the frequnecy
>   Max_index: 458
>   Sample rate: 44100.0
>   19724.4140625 is the frequnecy
>   Max_index: 17
>   Sample rate: 44100.0
>   732.12890625 is the frequnecy
>   Max_index: 129
>   Sample rate: 44100.0
>   5555.56640625 is the frequnecy
>   Max_index: 262
>   Sample rate: 44100.0
>   11283.3984375 is the frequnecy
>   Max_index: 259
>   Sample rate: 44100.0
>   11154.19921875 is the frequnecy
>   Max_index: 0
>   Sample rate: 44100.0
>   0.0 is the frequnecy
>   Max_index: 404
>   Sample rate: 44100.0
>   17398.828125 is the frequnecy
>   Max_index: 471
>   Sample rate: 44100.0
>   20284.27734375 is the frequnecy
>   Max_index: 119
>   Sample rate: 44100.0
>   5124.90234375 is the frequnecy
>   Max_index: 239
>   Sample rate: 44100.0
>   10292.87109375 is the frequnecy
>   Max_index: 385
>   Sample rate: 44100.0
>   16580.56640625 is the frequnecy
>   Max_index: 485
>   Sample rate: 44100.0
>   20887.20703125 is the frequnecy
>   Max_index: 14
>   Sample rate: 44100.0
>   602.9296875 is the frequnecy
>   Max_index: 384
>   Sample rate: 44100.0
>   16537.5 is the frequnecy
>   Max_index: 12
>   Sample rate: 44100.0
>   516.796875 is the frequnecy
>   Max_index: 342
>   Sample rate: 44100.0
>   14728.7109375 is the frequnecy
>   Max_index: 369
>   Sample rate: 44100.0
>   15891.50390625 is the frequnecy
>   Max_index: 15
>   Sample rate: 44100.0
>   645.99609375 is the frequnecy
>   Max_index: 22
>   Sample rate: 44100.0
>   947.4609375 is the frequnecy
>   Max_index: 395
>   Sample rate: 44100.0
>   17011.23046875 is the frequnecy
>   Max_index: 26
>   Sample rate: 44100.0
>   1119.7265625 is the frequnecy
>   Max_index: 386
>   Sample rate: 44100.0
>   16623.6328125 is the frequnecy

Comment: 1) It's pretty hard for me to tell what you're trying to do. 2) You actually have a DFT, not an FFT (just terminology). 3) You would normally convert the DFT result to polar coordinates. 3) Unless it's a pure sine tone, what a person hears as a single "sound" or "note" is actually made of many harmonics at many frequencies. 4) This sort of thing is waaaay beyond the scope of the site. You should read textbooks or if you just want to tinker you should use a library.

Comment: One resource I found helpful is here: http://www.dspguide.com/pdfbook.htm

Comment: @dav191 Your sampling frequency is 44100 Hz. But what is the actual frequency of the note played?

Comment: You might perhaps use an existing DFT implementation (e.g. one that is tested and known to work).  It will also be vastly more efficient.

Comment: Maybe try asking at http://dsp.stackexchange.com/  That site is dedicated to digital signal processing questions.

Comment: thank you brother @PhilFreihofner